# Is returning a ICollection when calling ToList efficient?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

Say I am doing this in my EF repository:

```
public ICollection<User> GetUsers(...) 
{
   return this.UserRepository.Get(....).ToList();
}
```

When I call ToList, does that convert it to a List and then get 'downgraded' or recasted to ICollection?

Would it be better just to do:

```
public IList<User> GetUsers(...);
```

**Is this the same thing or one is more effecient that the other i.e. more casting involved or the like.**

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: If you are returning it as a list, why not just make your return type `List`?

Comment: The main reason to do this is if you need to work with some explicitly implemented methods of ICollection<T> interface with the returned List<T>. Not sure if there are any but that would be the reason. Has nothing to do with efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no difference about efficiency.[`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inherit from `ICollection<T>`,You can return whichever you want.There is no **significant** difference.